# AppBar not working and considered as dead code

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

This is my code, it keeps showing up as "Dead Code." and it wont show anything in my AVD, can anyone help me with this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String routeName = "/sign_in";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
    AppBar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `AppBar()` should be inside the `Scaffold` widget.
The code should be something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String routeName = "/sign_in";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar();
    );
  }
}
```

Secondly when you use `return` the code below the `return` statement doesn't execute, that is the reason your ide shows as a "dead code"

Answer (score 0):

AppBar should be inside scaffold widget something like this.
try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Your Navigationbar title"),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Also after return statement code never execute so. Your ide showing you dead code.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation, it worked :)

Comment: most welcome. you can ask me anything related to mobile app development.